# array from localStorage and display in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I am getting the data not in the right column. What is the right way to do this?

```
//store the data into localStorage


/* dynamically draw the table, this is the part that I m not getting it right. What should I do to ge the value in the right column. */

function doShowAll() {
  if (CheckBrowser()) {
    var key = "";
    var list = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Item</th></tr>\n";
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
      key = localStorage.key(i);

      list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>" +
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) + "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    if (list == "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Item</th></tr>\n") {
      list += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
  } else {
    alert('Cannot store shopping list as your browser do not support local storage');
  }
}


/*
 * Checking the browser compatibility.
 */


function CheckBrowser() {
  if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    // we can use localStorage object to store data
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

/* dynamically draw the table, this is the part that I m not getting it right. What should I do to ge the value in the right column. */

Comment: Why are you storing an array in `localStorage` if it's only one item? Store the `user` object.

Comment: You don't need to check for browser-compatibility for `localStorage` anymore - it's been supported by all major browsers since IE8 in 2008.

Comment: Everything is correct. You are not rendering your <td>s correctly. Check it again. The header has 3 columns but the rows have only 2

Comment: You **should not** do this: `document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;` - you're opening yourself up to XSS attacks because you're blindly copying data from localStorage into the DOM. Instead you should use the DOM's `createElement` API to add content to the page in a safe manner - it's also MUCH faster.

Comment: @Barmar, have to convert to string to store more data.

Comment: Of course you have to convert to JSON. But why an array `[user.data, user.item]` instead of just `JSON.stringify(user)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you parse the JSON, you need to extract the `data` and `item` so you can show them in separate table columns.

```
function doShowAll() {
  if (CheckBrowser()) {
    var key = "";
    var list = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Item</th></tr>\n";
    var i = 0;

    if (localStorage.length == 0) {
      list += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td><td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>" +
          data[0] + "</td>" + data[1] + "</tr>\n";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
  } else {
    alert('Cannot store shopping list as your browser do not support local storage');
  }
}
```